# Dangling discs after cluster removal

Tags: kubernetes, ibm-cloud, billing

As a part of university course I had to deploy an application to IBM Kubernetes.
I have *pay-as-you-go* type of account with my credit card attached to it.

I deployed the application to the cluster (the paid tier with public IP) and after few days and the demonstration the cluster was not needed anymore.
The cluster was configured to use dynamic provisioning with persistent storage via  [ibmcloud-block-storage-plugin](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/containers?topic=containers-block_storage).

The problem is that the cluster provisioned tens of discs and then when I removed it using IBM Cloud UI (with option to remove all persistent volumes checked) the discs are still displayed as active.

Result of invoking `ibmcloud sl block volume-list`:

```
77394321   SL02SEL1854117-1    dal13        endurance_block_storage   20            -            161.26.114.100   0       1
78180815   SL02SEL1854117-2    dal10        endurance_block_storage   20            -            161.26.98.107    0       1
78180817   SL02SEL1854117-3    dal10        endurance_block_storage   20            -            161.26.98.107    1       1
78180827   SL02SEL1854117-4    dal10        endurance_block_storage   20            -            161.26.98.106    3       1
78180829   SL02SEL1854117-5    dal10        endurance_block_storage   20            -            161.26.98.108    2       1
78184235   SL02SEL1854117-6    dal10        endurance_block_storage   20            -            161.26.98.88     4       1
78184249   SL02SEL1854117-7    dal10        endurance_block_storage   20            -            161.26.98.86     5       1
78184285   SL02SEL1854117-8    dal10        endurance_block_storage   20            -            161.26.98.107    6       1
78184289   SL02SEL1854117-9    dal10        endurance_block_storage   20            -            161.26.98.105    7       1
78184457   SL02SEL1854117-10   dal10        endurance_block_storage   20            -            161.26.98.85     9       1
78184465   SL02SEL1854117-11   dal10        endurance_block_storage   20            -            161.26.98.88     8       1
78184485   SL02SEL1854117-12   dal10        endurance_block_storage   20            -            161.26.98.86     10      1
78184521   SL02SEL1854117-13   dal10        endurance_block_storage   20            -            161.26.98.106    0       1
78184605   SL02SEL1854117-14   dal10        endurance_block_storage   20            -            161.26.98.87     1       1
78184643   SL02SEL1854117-15   dal10        endurance_block_storage   20            -            161.26.98.85     2       1
78184689   SL02SEL1854117-16   dal10        endurance_block_storage   20            -            161.26.98.87     3       1
78184725   SL02SEL1854117-17   dal10        endurance_block_storage   20            -            161.26.98.108    11      1

[ ... more entries there ... ]
```

All of those discs was created using default ibm bronze block storage class for Kubernetes clusters and have standard `Remove` policy set (so should've been delted automatically).

When I'm trying to delete any of those with `ibmcloud sl block volume-cancel --immediate --force 77394321` I got:

```
Failed to cancel block volume: 77394321.
No billing item is found to cancel.
```

What's more the IBM Cloud displays those discs as active and there's no option to delete them (the option in the menu is grayed):

[image: Screenshot of grayed delete button]

I don't want to get billing for more than **40 x 20GB** discs as the cluster don't even need that many resources (the fault was in badly defined Kubernetes configs).

What is correct way to remove the discs or is it only a delay on IBM Cloud and everything will be fine with my billings (my billings show only around `$19` for public IP for cluster, nothing more)?

**Edit**
It seems that after some time the problem was resolved (I created a ticket, but don't know if the sales team solved the problem. Probably it was just enough to wait as @Sandip Amin suggested in comments).

Comment: Can you describe how you deleted the PVC/File Shares from the UI? Did you delete the cluster from the UI. Were you prompted to also delete file shares OR did you explicitly delete the PVCs. For reference: Docs on cleanup: https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/containers?topic=containers-cleanup There is a NOTES failed as part of the IaaS View. Can you dump an example out here?
ibmcloud sl block volume-list --columns id --columns notes | grep <pv_name>

Comment: Also, it make take up at least 24 hours + for it to be completely removed (in case the immediate deletion was a mistake by the user and wants to recover). When did u submit the deletion has it been more than 1+ days?

Answer (score 1):

Opening a support case would probably be the best course of action here as we'll likely need some account info from you to figure out what happened (or rather, why the expected actions *didn't* happen).

Log into the cloud and visit https://cloud.ibm.com/unifiedsupport/supportcenter (or click the Support link in the masthead of the page). If you'll comment back here with your case number, I'll help follow up on it.

Comment: I created a new ticket about the issue and got the following response: "Looks like, from the error you provided, the issue is due to missing billing items. I'll send this to sales to see if they can help with this." and it seems the IBM sales team solved the issue or that was just a delay. Anyway that number of storage made me panic a bit.